# Transferable belief model, Pignistic probability, pseudo-science?

Tags: decision-theory

I have to review an article for a conference. This article deals with Transferable belief model and Pignistic probability, concepts that were previously unknown to me (CS background).

I dived into these "theories" and all this came to me as a complete pseudo-science with very unclear concepts, out-of-the blue definitions and overly complexed vocabularies. Reading the Wikipedia talk pages on [Transferable belief model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Transferable_belief_model) and [Dempster–Shafer theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Dempster%E2%80%93Shafer_theory) conforted my opinion. Plus the fact that these articles are noted as of low importance.

However, I'm no expert in statistics and decision theory so I ask the community if these theories are backed by a rigorous background and if they have a proven track-record of applications and reproducible results ? As a researcher, I won't be convinced by a high number of citations of research articles.

I also asked the same question on [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244740/transferable-belief-model-pignistic-probability-pseudo-science), as I want to confront points of view.

(edit, typo)

Comment: I have nothing to say about the merits of these theories. At ay rate, I think the "official" Wikipedia page     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dempster–Shafer_theory      makes sense.

Comment: DST and the TBM are very deep and important fields with firm philosophical and mathematical foundations. Start with Wikipedia, then Google--there is a vast body of literature on both the theory and applications, especially DST.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have a stock whose value at time 0 is $S_0$ and at time 1 can take one of two possible values, $S_1\in\{a,b\}$ (corresponding to up-tick and down-tick in the price). Now you also have another financial security $V_1$ that depends on the value $S_1$ (for example, a call option). Since any two points determine a straight line, $V_1$ is a linear function of $S_1$. This allows us to find $V_0$, the price of the security at time 0, from $S_0$ using the linearity of pricing (the price of two cars is $2$ $\times$ the price of one car).

This is known as *risk-neutral pricing* and is a central part of mathematical finance.
Now suppose that $S_1\in\{a,b,c\}$ (three possible values) instead. Then the above type of argument only gives an interval for $V_0$, rather than an exact value.

While I don't know for sure, it seems that the theory of belief functions in Dempster–Shafer theory is related to this -- so we have some belief in a proposition $p$ without assigning an exact Bayesian probability to $p$. Here $V_0$ could be equal to 1 if $p$ is true and 0 otherwise.

In conclusion, this is certainly not pseudo-science, but seems like a useful way of organizing inconclusive evidence.